# Prevent bypassing of SSL Pinning in android application

Tags: certificates, android, burp-suite, sslstrip, tls-intercept

I am creating an android application which is able to ping the server for certain information and return them. There are a few methods by which a user can bypass the pinned SSL certificate of an android application by using tools like Frida, Objection, etc. 
Is there a way to prevent the bypass of SSL certificate in android. so that, the user cannot be able to see the traffic?
(assume the user phone is rooted)

Comment: Generally no. You can at most make it harder. Rooted phone = user can do anything.

Answer (score 2):

No there isn't. Your app is a guest on the system, the user is the owner of the device is the master. They get to decide what your app can or cannot do, and there isn't much you can do about it.